# Track API calls from Streamlit app in browser developer tools

Tags: python, browser, streamlit

Is there a way to track API calls made from a Streamlit app in the Network tab of the browser developer tools?

I made a Streamlit app that retrieves data through API calls to a server, but I can't find those calls in the developer tools. This will help me to debug and optimize the app more quickly.

Comment: Are you making the calls in the backend or frontend? As in are you using the python to make the calls?

Comment: I'm using package `requests` to make the calls, and I make then from the streamlit frontend.

Comment: Are you sure that the request is made from the browser and not from the streamlit app?

Comment: The call is inside the code of the streamlit app. When launching streamlit, its own server is started which handles the webapp. So it may be that in some way the Streamlit server "shadows" the api call, but I do not have so much detailed knowledge about the internal working of the browser and this possible interaction.

Comment: Yea so if it's the streamlit server making the API calls you'll need a proxy to intercept them. Maybe there is another solution I don't know though

Answer (score 1):

One soultion to this would be to use [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) with the [Postman interceptor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-interceptor/aicmkgpgakddgnaphhhpliifpcfhicfo).

The Chrome extension intercepts all web traffic and sends it to the Postman app where you can view it.

[Here's](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/capturing-request-data/interceptor/) a guide on how to set it up.

---

Another solution would be to use the [Postman proxy](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/capturing-request-data/capturing-http-requests/) to intercept and log all web traffic. Personally I couldn't get this to work on my computer so I used the solution above.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestions! I'm quite new to Postman and I didn't know them. The Postman proxy does not seem suitable for me too, since I'm on the work laptop which restricts me on network settings. I tried the Postman interceptor, and while it works, unfortunately I still cannot see the api calls made from the Streamlit app

Comment: That's interesting. I'll look into it and see if I find something